# How do you rotate a Polygon in an UIView without rotating the background

Tags: iphone, uiview

The following code:

http://pastie.org/pastes/835022

in a custom UIView rotates the entire view including the gradient background.

What is the proper way to rotate the polygon without rotating the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd separate your gradient from your polygon. Create a [gradient layer](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/) for the gradient. Put your polygon drawing into the [content layer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/contents). That should let your polygon be rotated without affecting the background.

Comment: Got the Gradient layer working, but now sure how to draw in the content layer

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/ProvidingCALayerContent.html That should provide some guidance on drawing into the content layer of a view.

Comment: Took out all the gradient stuff to try to get content layer to draw and implemented method per docs.  http://pastie.org/836160  The view draws completely black.  (sorry, n00b on Board)

Comment: Got drawing in the content layer working, turned gradient layer back on, but content not above gradient.  Gradient layer set to 0.